# Azure Service Fabric Actors Alternative?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, service-fabric-actor

I have an Event Hub with loads of ingress for telemetry kind of data and there is a worker for receiving these events and delegate the small processing work to an Actor on Service Fabric. Even though there is no data consistency problem while storing data out from these Actors they were basically picked up for a scalable and reliable way of handling these events. Now if I have decided to move away from Actors to a self developed logic on containers, what would be the best approach to handle processing of huge volumes of data with easy check points on Event Hub? 
I would like know possible problems that needs to be handled or the behaviors of Actor I would be missing.